# Vision Framework recognize image in video

Tags: image-recognition, vision, ios11

Is it possible to detect image in Video with usage of Vision Framework? This example https://github.com/jeffreybergier/Blog-Getting-Started-with-Vision shows how to track object on video that user previously tapped on. Is it possible to add image to project and detect if this image appears somewehre on video? I was looking into [VNTargetedImageRequest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/vntargetedimagerequest) but it's abstract class and Google returns 4 results about it.